# ASP não salva dados na session

Tags: session, asp

Tenho uma página que faz o login do cliente. Essa página sobe para a session o id e nome do cliente assim:

```vbscript
session("user_id") = rec_user("chave")
session("user_name") = rec_user("nome)
```

Tenho outra página que usa essas informações para verificar se o usuário está logado:

```vbscript
if session("user_id") = "" then
    response.redirect("login.asp")
else
    'exibe a página
end if
```

O problema é que a página que faz a verificação nunca recebe os dados da `session`. Achei o erro estranho por dois motivos:

- 1º assim que inseri os dados na `session`, na página de login, fim uma verificação para ver se estavam lá, e retornou positivo.
- 2º há uma outra página de login, que busca os usuários em uma tabela secundária, mas redireciona para a mesma página de verificação, e, estranhamente, os dados subidos para a `session` desta outra página de login são vistos perfeitamente pela página de verificação.

Comment: Não deve ter a ver com o assunto, mas o erro de digitação (a aspa faltando no nome) é só aqui no SOpt né? No código está ok?

Comment: Será que não existe algo mais no código dessa página primeira página de login, além dessas duas linhas que você colocou de exemplo? Teria como mostrar o código inteiro? É ASP puro, ou é ASP.Net?

Answer (score 2):

Bem galera. Achei o problema e vou compartilhar. O redirecionamento de páginas estava com endereço completo com o www. Exemplo

```
response.redirect('http://www.exemplo.com')
```

Porém se o usuário acessar sem o WWW (exemplo.com) no navegador, a página que recebe o redirecionamento (que vem com www na url) não enxerga a session criada na página que salvou os dados com url sem www. Eis a explicação por uma página de login funcionar e outra não. A solução foi simples, retirar o redirecionamento com url completa e colocar com url relativa.